# Minkowski sum of disks in 3D

Tags: geometry, 3d, sumset

Suppose we have a set of disks in $\Bbb R^3$. These disks are neither parallel nor perpendicular to each other. In general, is it possible to formulate (or write an equation for) the object constructed by the Minkowski sum of these disks?

Comment: The support function of a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be $$h(u) = \sup \{ x\cdot u \ :\ x\in S\}$$ The Minkowski sum of two convex sets $S$ and $T$ is characterized by the equation $$h_{S+T} = h_S + h_T$$ You can work it out from there.

Comment: @Deane Thanks a lot for providing a direction!